# Adding -prune and -name to the find command on AIX and Linux

Tags: linux, find, aix

I have to come up with a find command to find certain files in a directory. The directory has sub directories and sym-links to other directories. If I use the following find command it ignores the sym-links:

```
find $dir/ -name '*.out' -size 0 -mtime +0
```

The following follows the sym-links:

```
find -L $dir/ -name '*.out' -size 0 -mtime +0 2
```

I am trying to figure out a way to use `-prune` and additional `-name` flags to omit certain elements from the directory.  I need something that works on both Linux and AIX.

Some commands I've tried:

```
find -L . ( -name dest ) -prune -o -name "*.out"
find -L $dir -name *.out ( ! -name "dest" -prune )
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried with `-prune`?

Comment: Did you read documentation of `find` ? BTW you could compile and use [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) on your AIX system

Comment: @h3rrmiller Some commands that i tried without success   <br/> find -L . \( -name dest \) -prune -o -name "*.out"     <br/>  find -L $dir -name \*.out  \( ! -name "dest" -prune \)

Answer (score 2):

Without an "action" (like `-print`), `find` will print out each file it visits.  This behavior is why `find -L . ( -name dest ) -prune -o -name "*.out"` still shows the files you are pruning.  `find` has to visit the file before it can evaluate the conditions you provided.

Adding the `-print` action to the end of your `find` command should do the trick.

```
find -L . -name dest -prune -o -name "*.out" -print
```